# jQuery detect Chrome Frame

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that I'm using to detect what versions of a browser a user is using:

var browser = $.browser;

```
    if (browser.msie) {
        window.location.replace('/ChromeFrame');
    }
    else if (browser.mozilla && browser.version < 4) {
        window.location.replace('/Upgrade');
    }
    else if (browser.opera && browser.version < 11.5) {
        window.location.replace('/Upgrade');
    }
```

The idea is that if they are using IE then they must install Chrome Frame and if they are using less than Firefox 4 or Opera 11.5 then they must upgrade their browser (not not sure if the way I am doing that is correct?)

But in addition to checking if they are using IE I need to detect if they have Chrome Frame so I can let IE users in.

Can anyone help? Thanks

I've thought about doing something like: `(browser.msie && !navigator.userAgent.contains('chromeframe'))`

Comment: Seriously, don’t do this. Use [feature detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh273397(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can detect Chrome Frame by looking for `window.externalHost` like this:

```
if(window.externalHost){
  alert("I'm running in Chrome Frame")
}
```

Source: [Chrome Frame: Developer Guide‎](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/understanding-chrome-frame-user-agent#TOC-From-the-script-on-the-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use the [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/#jQuery-browser1) and [jQuery.browser.version](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/#jQuery-browser-version2) properties.

You may use the [chrome.management.get](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/management.html) to do it! :)

Comment: I am using both as shown in my OP. But how would I detect Chrome Frame with them?

Comment: -1 this answer does not provide a solution at all. jQuery.brwoser is not usable to detect Chrome Frame and chrome.management.get seems to be for extensions in Chrome, not to detect Chrome Frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at ChromeFrame script :
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js

Their CF detection is like this :

```
var b = navigator.userAgent,
    c = /MSIE (\S+); Windows NT/,
    g = false;
if (c.test(b)) {
    if (parseFloat(c.exec(b)[1]) < 6 && b.indexOf("SV1") < 0) g = true
} else g = true;
if (!g) {
    alert('Chrome Frame Not Installed')
}
```